# AMS, activerecord-postgis-adapter and Heroku serializes string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, active-model-serializers

I'm using active_model_serializer 0.8.3 with another gem called activerecord-postgis-adapter on Heroku.
When I try to serialize a column with geographic coordinates the AMS serializes an string instead of an object RGeo::Geographic. Locally it works but not on Heroku. Any suggestion?

**Got:** 0101000020E61000003F8C101E6D5447C0E6CB0BB08F8637C0 
**Expected:** RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x3ff94be17f4c "POINT (-44.7727999 -20.18731)

```
class CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :location

  def location
    lonlat = object.lonlat
    { lon: lonlat.x, lat: lonlat.y }
  end
end
```

So when I try to use 'x' method, I got an error because string does not have the method x.

Comment: One suggestion: add some code so that we have a fair chance of diagnosing the issue. I'm guessing that you need to add some logic in your serializer since AMS is calling `to_s` on the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks max. I've added the code.